# How to upload multiple files to OneDrive

Tags: c#, api, graph, onedrive

I use the MS Graph API to migrate data to OneDrive. 
The total data size is 100Gb +.

Currently I am doing the following:

When I am in a folder I use FileStream to get the file:

```
foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(startPath))
        {
            using (FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                await WriteFilesToOneDriveAsync(graphClien, stream, user, fileName, folderId);
            }
        }
```

When I have the first file I upload it to OneDrive using this method:

```
 var driveItemList = await graphServiceClient.Users[user.Id].Drive.Root.Children.Request().GetAsync();

                if (!driveItemList.Any(x => x.Name == fileName))
                {
                    UploadSession uploadSession = null;

                    uploadSession = await graphServiceClient.Users[user.Id].Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(fileName).CreateUploadSession().Request().PostAsync();

                    var uploadProvider = new ChunkedUploadProvider(uploadSession, graphServiceClient, stream);
                    var chunks = uploadProvider.GetUploadChunkRequests();
                    var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

                    foreach (var (chunk, i) in chunks.WithIndex())
                    {
                        var chunkRequestResponse = await uploadProvider.GetChunkRequestResponseAsync(chunk, exceptions);

                        Console.WriteLine($"Uploading chunk {i} out of {chunks.Count()}");

                        if (chunkRequestResponse.UploadSucceeded)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Upload is complete", chunkRequestResponse.ItemResponse);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    logger.Info($"File Exists {fileName}");
                }
```

This code works very well. 
It allows me to upload files to OneDrive.

My problem now is that I have speed problems. 
It would take several hours to upload 100Gb into OneDrive. 
According to the Microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/sharepoint-online-and-onedrive-migration-speed

> Package size. To improve migration throughput, we recommend that you
>   package at least 250 files per transfer. For the transfer size, we
>   recommend a minimum of 100 MB and less than 250 MB per package.
>   Keeping within these guidelines will result in a faster upload speed
>   to Azure and leverages the scale capabilities of the migration API.

If I have a folder with 10 files (Excel, text files ...) how can I merge these files into one package ?

Comment: Not sure if Microsoft means package like zip file. If this could be a solution for you... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.extracttodirectory?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You think I should zip the folders first ?

Comment: It could improve the performance if you upload several bigger zip files instead of many smaller files. But as far as I know, there is no extraction tool on OneDrive. If you are happy to have zipped content on OneDrive, I would try this solution. Just thought.